# React, Apollo 2, GraphQL, Authentication. How to re-render component after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/507w9qxrrl

I don't understand:

1) **How to re-render() `Menu`** component after:

```
this.props.client.query({
  query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY,
  fetchPolicy: "network-only"
});
```

If I login() I expect my `Menu` component to re-render() itself. But nothing.
Only if I click on the Home link it re-render() itself. I suspect because I'm using this to render it:

```
<Route component={Menu} />
```

for embrace it in react-router props. Is it wrong?

Plus, if inspect `this.props` of Menu after `login()` I see `loading: true` forever. Why?

2) **How to prevent `Menu` component to query if not authenticated** (eg: there isn't a token in localStorage); I'm using in `Menu` component this code:

```
export default graphql(CURRENT_USER_QUERY)(Menu);
```

3) **Is this the right way to go?**

Comment: `<Route component={Menu} />` I didn't seem to find this line of code.?

Comment: Is commented because I'm trying to use it without.

Comment: @Dane, if I remove that line and use just `<Menu />` it doesn't re-render at all.

Comment: I reset the code as in question.

Comment: About **(2)**, you can easily skip queries as explained here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-skip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me answer your second question: You can skip an operation using the [*skip* query option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-skip).

```
export default graphql(CURRENT_USER_QUERY, {
  skip: () => !localStorage.get("auth_token"),
})(Menu);
```

The problem now is how to re-render this component when the local storage changes. Usually react does not listen on the local storage to trigger a re-render, instead a re-render is done using one of this three methods:

1. The component's state changes
2. The parent of the component re-renders (usually with new props for the child)
3. [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) is called on the component

(Note that also a change of a subscribed context will trigger a re-render but we don't want to mess around with context ;-))

You might want to go with a combination of 2. and 3. or 1. and 2.
In your case it can be enough to change the route (as you do in the login function). If this does not work you can call `this.forceUpdate()` on the App component after Login using a callback property on `<Login onLogin={() => this.forceUpdate() } />`.

Comment: The `skip` option is amazing. In my example below I basically extracted the whole query so that I could control it in the component lifecycle methods.

Comment: Other than that I do not believe that forceUpdate is the solution that John is looking for. Redux is. Because you don't really want to use forceUpdate - although I used it in my example source code too because there was no other option.

Comment: I feel like Redux is a bit of an overkill here to save one property. We have a big Apollo app and we don't use Redux at all. Instead we use a bit of React state to save a few things (usually UI state) that are not in the server's state. Instead of Redux you could create a "userIsLoggedIn" state property on the App component. And then the question is if a forceUpdate is not more elegant since you won't have two sources of truth for the login. Redux does not really unify this since you want to keep login state through page reloads.

Comment: Yea I spent quite a lot of time on GitHub helping this guy and even in one of my older examples I stored the userIsLoggedIn flag in App component. The problem with that is that you would either want to use `context` or you would potentially have to pass the `userIsLoggedIn` flag to every component that needs to know if the user is logged in manually. You can prevent yourself from this headache by using redux.

Comment: Redux is basically is a fancy state manager. Not using it saves you a couple of `kbs` because you don't have one more dependency but using it makes your project a lot more extendable. Apollo takes care of server-side application state. Redux is here because of client-side application state. These are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED**

**1)** I just created new link https://codesandbox.io/s/0y3jl8znw

You want to fetch the user data in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.props.client.query({query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY})
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: response.data.currentUser})
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('there was an error ', e)
    })
  }
```

This will make the component re-render.

**2)** Now when we moved the query call in the component's lifecycle method we have full control over it. If you want to call the query only if you have something in localstorage you just need to wrap the query in a simple condition:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    if(localstora.getItem('auth_token')) {
      this.props.client.query({query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY})
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ currentUser: response.data.currentUser})
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('there was an error ', e)
      })
    }
  }
```

**3)** You want to store the global application state in redux store. Otherwise you will have to fetch the user info every time you need to work with it. I would recommend to define a `state` in you `App` component and store all the global values there.

Comment: You think there is no way to work without App state? I don't believe I can't use the power of Apollo!

Comment: Also I read online that many people are turning off Redux with Apollo 2. But I don't understand how! This problem is a basic one. Doesn't it?

Comment: Redux is basically a "global" app's state. It is perfectly fine to save user information in `App` component. Why would you call API every time you need to work with user information? :) It is perfectly fine to store information that is not sensitive in your components.

Comment: I would love to show you power of redux but I need to get back to work. :D

Comment: Thanks @Michal, but there is still a problem: if in my Menu I need `currentUser` information I think I should go with something like this: `export default graphql(CURRENT_USER_QUERY)(Menu);` and also if I use Redux like you said it on first render throw "Unauthorized" because of no token present.

Comment: You don't need to refetch the user data because you already fetched it when user logged in. However if you need to fetch additional user data you have two options 1) create nested component in your menu component that will be wrapped in the `graphql` HOC component and you will render that component only if user is logged in. 2) You can use `branch` from recompose but that is a little bit advanced: https://medium.com/@tkh44/using-recomposes-branch-to-conditionally-render-components-942df8034cd8

Comment: The short answer to that is you don't want to fetch the query because you don't need to. :)

Comment: You can also use `apolloClient.query` insted of the `graphql HOC` and fetch the query only when you want to but as I said above you don't need to make the app more complicated for no reason. :)

Comment: Ok @Michal, but I need to refetch when I refresh the page with my token in localStorage, no? I was talking about this case. Anyway, how to use `apolloClient.query`? I need to use `withApollo()`, right?

Comment: Anyway I FOUND THE PROBLEM IN MY CODE! `this.props.client.query({` ---> `await this.props.client.query({` and IT WORKS! So I think this is the problem of no re-rendering(). Maybe the following code is blocking the fetch: `this.props.history.push(`/`);`.

Comment: Ha ha nice. You are right. I just edited the answer. The only thing I changed is the `Menu` component. When you click on login it will take a couple of milliseconds before the menu re-renders because it takes a while before you get response from the server after logging in. Ideally you should wait for server to respond and then redirect user to homepage.

Comment: I just updated the `_confirm` method. Now the app works properly. (it shows loader, it redirects user when the call to API is finished)

Comment: Thanks @Michal but we are not good: 1) I receive this in console: `Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Login component.`. 2) I think we don't need Redux. We can just work with Apollo Cache. Because everything is already there. You talk about "refetch", but it doesn't. I fetch just one time my currentUser info. Then I store that info in my Apollo Cache and with re-render the components know them. I just need an how-to!

Comment: And then if you reload the page nothing happens! Also with token in localStorage.

Comment: You don't use the token anywhere after you set it. Maybe like this? :) https://codesandbox.io/s/0y3jl8znw

Comment: Maybe one of the problems is this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733633/react-apollo-2-with-react-router-graphql-hoc-loading-true-forever-if-i-navigat

Comment: And this error after login: `Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.` ???

Comment: I was calling the set state after react router unmounted the component. I fixed couple of other small things this should look a lot better now :) https://codesandbox.io/s/0y3jl8znw

Comment: It's a lot better, but maybe instaed of check the component state `currentUser` I can use the power of Apollo and try with something like: `client.query({query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY})` because if are in cache I see that data, if not it make a network request and I can also handle the error "unauthorized" if I don't want check also the localStorage token. I need this also for example if I need the currentUser info in other components. I don't like the component state for this. Maybe the App one (or maybe Redux), but what I wanna say to you is that I already have the Apollo Cache with data!!!!

Comment: You are making things too complicated for no reason. What exactly happens when you call graphql query? Cache first? Cache only? Network first? Just use the react state it is fine.

Comment: Sorry @Michal. Why to not use what Apollo just give us? It's cache is like a Redux one. Except for what I don't have in Backend. They are just developing this: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state infact. What I want now is to use just Apollo and React (no apollo-link-state) and my problem is that I need to reuse `currentUser` info across my entire App, I hate local component state. You r work is very good, just incomplete. But we have to make it AMAZING! Any idea?

Comment: I believe that I answered your question and provided more than enough source code. :) Maybe you can create another question where I can show you how to implement redux.