# React Apollo 2 with React Router. graphql HOC loading: true forever if I navigate

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

This is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/p90q6674qq

I simply use:

```
export default graphql(CURRENT_USER_QUERY)(Menu);
```

on the `Menu` component and simply this code in `App` component:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <Menu /> */}
        <Route component={Menu} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A bug?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I was able to get some more info by adding `apollo-link-logger`. https://imgur.com/a/bGPjI The issue seems to be related to an unauthorized error, but it's surprising that for some reason it goes back to the loading state after error.

Comment: When you click on the menu, can you see a response in Console -> Network?